# Establishing an SMTP email server?

Tags: smtp

Server: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587
Username: myemail@gmail.com
Password: mygmailpassword

What is the issue here? My email server does not seem to be working despite turning on POP3 on my gmail account. Also tried turning on both IMAP and POP3..with no luck

P.S. This is being used for OSQA

Comment: do you have any debug output as to exactly y it isnt working? Auth error? Is it even trying to get the mail? etc

p.s. OSQA looks like stackoverflows twin :P

Comment: I am merely putting the values in the settings page on OSQA. Any suggestion on how to get the output?

Comment: Have you tried what is [shown here](http://meta.osqa.net/questions/6048/email-sending-has-stopped-working-how-to-debug)? Doesnt look very neat but seems to be a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

> **What is the issue here?**

The main issue is the absence of diagnostic feedback.

Another issue is that the question's title is about SMTP but the body is about POP3/IMAP. These are different protocols used for different purposes. An SMTP client cannot communicate witha POP3 or IMAP service and vice versa. Most clients use SMTP for **sending** mail and POP3/IMAP for **collecting received** email.

Use tcpdump or wireshark to watch OSQA attempting to collect email. Look for errors being reported by Gmail or connection failures.

Use tcpdump or wireshark to watch a normal POP3 or IMAP client communicating with your Gmail account, compare with what OSQA is doing.